# In Wicket 9.x, how do a include javascript and css via Behavior renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response)?

Tags: resources, response, upgrade, wicket

I have this code that works in Wicket 8.x but does not work in Wicket 9.x:

```
...
public class FancyComboBoxBehavior extends Behavior
{
  ...
  @Override
  public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response)
  {
     response.render(CssHeaderItem.forReference(CSS_REF));
     response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forReference(JS_REF));
     if (initJS)        
       response
         .render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forScript("$('select').selectBoxIt();","fancyComboBoxInit"));
  }
  ...
}
```

Like I said, in Wicket 8.x, I add this behavior to a page, then when I go to that page in the browser, right click on the page and pick View Source, I can search the page for .js and find the javascript file defined in JS_REF, I can search for .css and find the css file defined in CSS_REF.  I can search for selectBoxIt() and find the <script/> tag added to the response.  In Wicket 9.x, I cannot find either of the files nor can I find the <script/> tag for the .selectBoxIt() call.

Answer (score 2):

by default Wicket 9 has a CSP policy active by default. This prevents inline JavaScript and CSS code from been rendered and executed. You can easily disable CSP adding the following line to your app init() method:

```
public void init() {
  getCspSettings().blocking().disabled();
}
```

For more info check the migration guide here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+9.0

Comment: Yes, that is what I did to make renderHead work in classes that subclass Page, unfortunately, classes that subclass Behavior, while debugging I can see renderHead get called, I can step through it, but none of the CSS or JS actually makes it into the response that the browser receives.  So I guess there may be a bug in Wicket 9.x or perhaps resources for Behaviors that add no HTML to the page get ignored, I still don't know why renderHead on Pages work as expected but on Behaviors renderHead has no actual effect on the response.

Comment: @RobertoMurphy Please create a mini application showing this problem and attach it to a ticket in JIRA! Thank you!